# Mysql has gone away media temple

Tags: mysql

Would really like some help.

I keep getting the error Mysql has gone away when uploading a large file 75mb. Anything below 20mb uploads fine.

So i have looked into this error on other post within here. I am on media temple but they say its outside their scope unfortunately.

i have edited this file my.cnf at /etc/my.cnf

```
[client]
port            = 3306
socket          = /var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock

[mysqld_safe]
log-error=/var/log/mysqld.log
pid-file=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid

innodb_buffer_pool_size=2M
innodb_additional_mem_pool_size=500K
innodb_log_buffer_size=500K
innodb_thread_concurrency=2

[mysqld]
local-infile=0
datadir=/var/lib/mysql
user=mysql
symbolic-links=0

max_connections = 150
wait_timeout = 600
query-cache-type = 1
query-cache-size = 16M
query_cache_limit = 2M
thread_cache_size = 16
tmp_table_size = 32M
max_heap_table_size = 32M
join_buffer_size = 2M
table_open_cache = 128

port            = 3306
socket          = /var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock
skip-external-locking
key_buffer_size = 16M
max_allowed_packet = 1M
sort_buffer_size = 512K
net_buffer_length = 8K
read_buffer_size = 256K
read_rnd_buffer_size = 512K
myisam_sort_buffer_size = 8M

innodb_buffer_pool_size = 16M
innodb_additional_mem_pool_size = 2M
innodb_log_buffer_size = 8M

[mysqldump]
quick
max_allowed_packet = 16M

[mysql]
no-auto-rehash

[myisamchk]
key_buffer_size = 20M
sort_buffer_size = 20M
read_buffer = 2M
write_buffer = 2M
```

So i have uped the wait timeout section to 600 which should be more than enough?

i have my php.ini file set as follows.

```
[PHP]
soap.wsdl_cache_limit = 5
include_path = ".:"
cli_server.color = On
mysql.allow_persistent = On
mysqli.max_persistent = -1
session.bug_compat_42 = Off
mysql.connect_timeout = -1
session.use_only_cookies = 1
register_argc_argv = Off
mssql.min_error_severity = 10
open_basedir = "/var/www/vhosts/s3bubble.com/:/tmp/"
session.name = PHPSESSID
mysqlnd.collect_statistics = On
session.hash_function = 0
session.gc_probability = 1
log_errors_max_len = 1024
mssql.secure_connection = Off
pgsql.max_links = -1
variables_order = "GPCS"
ldap.max_links = -1
sybct.allow_persistent = On
max_input_time = 600
odbc.max_links = -1
session.save_handler = files
mysqli.cache_size = 2000
pgsql.auto_reset_persistent = Off
error_reporting = E_ALL & ~E_DEPRECATED & ~E_STRICT
auto_prepend_file =
sendmail_path = /usr/sbin/sendmail -t -i
sybct.min_client_severity = 10
pgsql.max_persistent = -1
auto_globals_jit = On
soap.wsdl_cache_ttl = 86400
allow_url_fopen = On
zend.enable_gc = On
mysqli.allow_persistent = On
tidy.clean_output = Off
display_startup_errors = Off
user_dir =
session.cookie_lifetime = 0
mysqli.max_links = -1
default_socket_timeout = 900
session.serialize_handler = php
session.hash_bits_per_character = 5
unserialize_callback_func =
pdo_mysql.cache_size = 2000
default_mimetype = "text/html"
session.cache_expire = 180
max_execution_time = 600
mail.add_x_header = On
upload_max_filesize = 1G
ibase.max_links = -1
safe_mode = off
zlib.output_compression = Off
ignore_repeated_errors = Off
odbc.max_persistent = -1
mssql.compatability_mode = Off
file_uploads = On
```

So i have uped the timeout any help this is driving me crazy anything any suggestions

Here is the script;

```
public function Uploader()
{
    header("Expires: Mon, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT");
    header("Last-Modified: " . gmdate("D, d M Y H:i:s") . " GMT");
    header("Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate");
    header("Cache-Control: post-check=0, pre-check=0", false);
    header("Pragma: no-cache");


    $targetDir = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/uploads/' . $this->session->userdata('account_id') . '/folder/' . $_REQUEST['playlist_id'];
    if (!file_exists($targetDir)) {
        mkdir($targetDir, 0777);
    }
    // Get parameters
    $chunk = isset($_REQUEST["chunk"]) ? intval($_REQUEST["chunk"]) : 0;
    $chunks = isset($_REQUEST["chunks"]) ? intval($_REQUEST["chunks"]) : 0;
    $fileName = isset($_REQUEST["name"]) ? $_REQUEST["name"] : '';

    // Clean the fileName for security reasons
    $fileName = preg_replace('/[^\w\._]+/', '_', $fileName);

    // Make sure the fileName is unique but only if chunking is disabled
    if ($chunks < 2 && file_exists($targetDir . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $fileName)) {
        $ext = strrpos($fileName, '.');
        $fileName_a = substr($fileName, 0, $ext);
        $fileName_b = substr($fileName, $ext);

        $count = 1;
        while (file_exists($targetDir . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $fileName_a . '_' . $count . $fileName_b)) {
            $count++;
        }

        $fileName = $fileName_a . '_' . $count . $fileName_b;
    }

    $filePath = $targetDir . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $fileName;

    // Create target dir
    if (!file_exists($targetDir)) {
        @mkdir($targetDir);
    }

    // Look for the content type header
    if (isset($_SERVER["HTTP_CONTENT_TYPE"])) {
        $contentType = $_SERVER["HTTP_CONTENT_TYPE"];
    }

    if (isset($_SERVER["CONTENT_TYPE"])) {
        $contentType = $_SERVER["CONTENT_TYPE"];
    }

    // Handle non multipart uploads older WebKit versions did not support multipart in HTML5
    if (strpos($contentType, "multipart") !== false) {
        if (isset($_FILES['file']['tmp_name']) && is_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'])) {
            // Open temp file
            $out = fopen("{$filePath}.part", $chunk == 0 ? "wb" : "ab");
            if ($out) {
                // Read binary input stream and append it to temp file
                $in = fopen($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], "rb");

                if ($in) {
                    while ($buff = fread($in, 4096)) {
                        fwrite($out, $buff);
                    }
                } else {
                    die('{"jsonrpc" : "2.0", "error" : {"code": 101, "message": "Failed to open input stream."}, "id" : "id"}');
                }
                fclose($in);
                fclose($out);
                @unlink($_FILES['file']['tmp_name']);
            } else {
                die('{"jsonrpc" : "2.0", "error" : {"code": 102, "message": "Failed to open output stream."}, "id" : "id"}');
            }
        } else {
            die('{"jsonrpc" : "2.0", "error" : {"code": 103, "message": "Failed to move uploaded file."}, "id" : "id"}');
        }
    } else {
        // Open temp file
        $out = fopen("{$filePath}.part", $chunk == 0 ? "wb" : "ab");
        if ($out) {
            // Read binary input stream and append it to temp file
            $in = fopen("php://input", "rb");

            if ($in) {
                while ($buff = fread($in, 4096)) {
                    fwrite($out, $buff);
                }
            } else {
                die('{"jsonrpc" : "2.0", "error" : {"code": 101, "message": "Failed to open input stream."}, "id" : "id"}');
            }

            fclose($in);
            fclose($out);
        } else {
            die('{"jsonrpc" : "2.0", "error" : {"code": 102, "message": "Failed to open output stream."}, "id" : "id"}');
        }
    }

    // Check if file has been uploaded
    if (!$chunks || $chunk == $chunks - 1) {

        $response = shell_exec("cd {$targetDir}/ && runs some script here 2>&1");

        $data = array(
            'filename' => $fileName,

        );

        if ($response) {
            //Add values to database
            $this->uploader_model->addFileData($data);

        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Are you uploading the 75MB file and saving it into mySQL or saving it on the server?

Comment: i am saving it on the server and just saving the path to the file to mysql

Comment: Can you post the script that is doing the uploading?

Comment: i have added the upload script steve

Comment: How long does it take to run the `shell_exec`? And are you restarting mysql after all of these configuration changes? Lastly, look at your framework's options and see how it's handling the database connection. I have a feeling your database connection is staying open from the start of your script through your save function, instead of opening at the moment you need to save to the database.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please increase the time of [wait_timeout](http://support.dropletz.com/content/how-fix-%E2%80%9Cmysql-server-has-gone-away%E2%80%9D-error-2006)

> Two possible reasons may be:-
>
> 1. Server timed out and closed the connection. How to fix: check that
>      **wait_timeout** variable in your mysqld’s my.cnf/my.ini  configuration
>      file is large enough.
> 2. Server dropped an incorrect or too large packet. If mysqld gets a
>      packet that is too large or incorrect, it assumes that something has
>      gone wrong with the client and closes the connection. You can
>      increase the maximal packet size limit by increasing the value of
>      **max_allowed_packet** in my.cnf/my.ini  file.

Comment: i have increased the wait_timeout to 600 which is 10 minutes which is more than enough it tends to put the file on the server in under 2 minutes?

Comment: I would argue that 600 seconds for a `wait_timeout` is more than enough in most setups.

Comment: @StevenV:- But dont you think that the file size is too big and it may take more time!!!

Comment: i am doing some editing to the file via php shell_exec before it saves to the database

Comment: hi rahul what would you suggest setting max_allowed_packet to?

Comment: @user1503606:- I am not very sure but try to increase it to 64 or 75 may be!!

Comment: increasing that to 64M didnt help i am still getting a 500 internal error mysql has gone away

Comment: Could you please try to increase the time as well as what I can observe is that the last comment you exactly 10 minutes before!! :)

Comment: ok it seems to be working now i maxed the max_allowed_packet to 100M and the wait_timeout 1200 thanks guys

Comment: i seems that my max_allowed_packet has to be higher than the filesize uploaded just tried a 150mb file and it didnt work so i have now uped it to 800M i have no idea if this is far to extreme a setting for max_allowed_packet